# Cannot load files from a concatenated path

Tags: arrays, bash, diff

I am working on a script that will run daily.  The script will compare individual configuration files from multiple host on one day with individual configuration files from a previous day.  I am working on a CentOS host I have limited access to - meaning I can't make major changes.

#### Details

1. My hosts are running a cron job that uploads their configuration file to an sftp server in a generic stable directory (/var/log/Backups) by hostname (hostname.txt).
2. A cron job on the server creates a date stamped directory and moves the files from /var/log/Backups to /var/log/Backups/ddmmyyyy.
3. Later, well after all sftp and file move operations I want to load an array with the file names in a current directory and I load an array with matching file names from the previous days directory.
4. I want a script to diff the matching file names and output the information to a single text file.
   I can't get the array to load the current days files and echo them to the terminal. I get a file operation error.

#### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set current date
now=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
echo $now

base=/var/log/GmonBackups/
loc=$base$now
echo $loc

# Load files from /var/log/GmonBackups/$now into an array

t_files=`ls loc`
echo $t_files
```

Comment: Try running with bash -x so you can see what is being done. Also your date format is dd-mm-yyyy but in step 2 you say you want ddmmyyyy. Which is correct? Also you want t_files=(\`ls $loc\`) to create an array of files in loc.

Comment: You are right.  I will correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might help you get further:

```
today=$(date +%d%m%Y)
yesterday=$(date --date=yesterday +%d%m%Y)

base=/var/log/GmonBackups

today_dir=$base/$today
yesterday_dir=$base/$yesterday

today_files=( $today_dir/* )
yesterday_files=( $yesterday_dir/* )
```

A few points:

- prefer $() to ``
- don't use ls to get your list of files because [it's not robust](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- I didn't put quotes around the variables because there are no spaces in your directory names.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance!  It's been 10 years since I've done any scripting and I need the refresh.

Comment: @DaleSmith if you have further questions or comments please let me know, if you want to thank me then please accept my answer.